# Deploying Flask app on a vps (Apache/Debian)

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to deploy a Flask app on a vps which OS is Debian and which is using Apache. I'm completely new to Apache so my problem may look simple but yet I was not able to find any solution on the web (I read a couple of tutorials and searched in this forum).

The server is running fine (it is already used for other purposes). When I try to access my app with www.myservername/web_app I get a 404 Not Found Error. Following http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/mod_wsgi/, here is what I've done:

I placed my application in /var/www/web_app/. In /var/www/web_app/app/**init**.py I created an instance of my app (named app) and configured it.

I placed the following .wsgi file in /var/www/web_app/:

```
activate_this = '/var/www/web_app/.pyenv/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this)
import sys
from app import app as application
```

Here is the /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf file (the site is enabled) :

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory /var/www/html/redmine>
    RailsBaseURI /redmine
    PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
    </Directory>
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess app user=www-data group=www-data threads=5 
    WSGIScriptAlias /web_app /var/www/web_app/app.wsgi
    <Directory /var/www/web_app>
            WSGIProcessGroup app
            WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I also tried to replace /web_app with /var/www/web_app in the WSGIScriptAlias and also to access myservername/var/www/web_app. Moreover I tried to comment out the Rails/Passenger directives in the first Directory tag.

Of course I installed the wsgi module. I restarted the server before trying to access the page. Here is the access log:

```
... "GET /web_app HTTP/1.1" 404 508
```

And the error log :

```
[error] ... File does not exist : /var/www/web_app
```

Finally, my flask app - when using flask development server - works fine.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you have an existing site defined, this new virtual host will be ignored because it doesn't define a ``ServerName`` directive with different host name. If it needs to be under same existing hostname but at a sub URL, that configuration needs to be integrated into the existing virtual host definition.

Comment: I integrated the configuration into the exiting virtual host definition and I still get 404 Not Found. (I edited my post)

Comment: Need to see what you are integrating it with. If your existing configuration had ``Alias /`` for some reason, or strange rewrite rules, can override mod_wsgi. Anyway, as your example stands right now, you should be using ``/web_app`` in browser, not ``/myapp``.

Comment: @Graham Dumpleton I edited my post and fixed the typos concerning /web_app and my_app.

Comment: Is this another typo? ``WSGIDaemon Process app user=www-data group=www-data threads=5 $``. Space in ``WSGIDaemonProcess`` and ends with ``$``. These would produce a Apache error if that is what you had.

Comment: Yes it was, sorry.

Comment: Can you temporarily comment out the Rails/Passenger directives. I wouldn't be surprised if the way they work it short circuits normal Apache processing and mod_wsgi never even gets a chance to handle it.

Comment: Still does not work with those two directives commented out.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton it turned out that /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default was linked to another file in /etc/apache2/sites-available/. Anyway, integrating the configuration into the existing virtual host definition was indeed the solution. Thank you!